# Is there a way of making short CSS columns maintain column-count?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have this example layout using CSS columns:

```
.col-container {
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 1em;
  column-width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  .col {
    break-inside: avoid;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    &:nth-child(1) {
      background: blue;
      height: 200px;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      background: green;
      height: 30px;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      background: red;
      height: 300px;
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
      background: grey;
      height: 275px;
    }
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/davidreeder/pen/QWJEzog

As per the CSS, it should maintain a 4 column layout, but because the green column is so short, it ends up stacking below the previous column.

The issue I have, is when content is added or changed, the layout then jumps back to 4 columns.

Is there a way of preventing that stacking using CSS?

Comment: `.col { break-before: column; }` ?